# Retrieving multiple images from firestore using pyrebase

Tags: firebase-storage, pyrebase

I'm using pyrebase to access my images stored in firebase storage for my python app. I access individual images via the below and this works fine:

```
    path = "images/profile_photo/" + self.local_id + ".jpeg"
    self.my_firestore.storage.child("images/profile_photo/" + self.local_id).download(path, "profile_picture.jpeg")
```

However, I need a user to be able to access lots of photos at once (coule be 50+). Is there a better way to retrieve the images than using .download() - is this going to download all the images and store them on the users phone? Would it not take lots of storage on the users phone?